# Can I boot my Hyper-V snapshot in 20 years

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v

At work, I have recently been servicing 17 year old embedded code. To build the binary, I needed to find somebodys old windows 98 computer with a 19 year old IAR compiler that was stashed away for the same purpose. Luckily, it was able to boot and we could still buy licenses from IAR.

Right now, I am releasing for a product that may need service in 17 years.

If I make a Hyper-V (VM-Ware or Virtualbox) snapshot of the PC that built the binary, will I be able to boot it in 20 years?

Comment: Just make sure to disable Windows updates before connecting to the Internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No one can say. The only guarantee that you could boot it in 20 years would be to preserve the hardware, OS and the current version of hypervisor software you have created the VM on. Even if Hyper-V/VMWare/VirtualBox are still available in 20 years time, there is nothing to say the current versions of the time will support the Win 98 VMs.